# Property marked with JsonIgnore is still shown in Swagger UI documentation for Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Swashbuckle package which integrates swagger with Web API project. I want to hide the property marked as Ignored in the documentation. I tried to use different ways such as IgnoreDataMember, DataContract & DataMember, JsonIgnore or XmlIgnore but nothing seems to work with swagger ui.

However, in default API documentation it works as expected. This is how my model looks like:

```
public partial class Model : BaseSettingsModel
{
    public string ReceiptTitle { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public FieldsEnum Fields { get; set; }

    public string DisplayFields { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: did you ever solved it? I experience similar problem

Comment: well never tried after that just left as is at that time.

Answer (score 3):

Moving from version 1.3.0 to 1.3.6  will solve this for you. At least `@JsonIgnore` and `@XmlTransient` are being respected.

For JsonIgnore you need to pull in the JSON.net NuGet package.